# Am I allowed to use text(snippets) from the iOS Developer Lib for my documentation?

Tags: licensing, documentation

At the moment, I create a Java-Wrapper for Apples *.pkpass-Files (Passbook).
Since I need to parse a JSon-File, I planned to add java doc to every field, so one know what exactly this field is in the pkpass and how it should be displayed. (There are some other meta data which are interesting).

At https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW1 you can see a description of this file format.

So, my question is: am I allowed to use text snippets (or the whole text) from the description column when I add also the link to the page into the java doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the following link: [Rights and Permissions](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/rightsandpermissions.html) from Apple's legal page on intellectual property

It says the following:

> If you have any questions concerning the usage or licensing of Apple copyrighted materials, for example, photographs, video footage, Apple advertisements or other Apple materials, please submit your detailed request in writing. Please be sure to include any surrounding copy or text to the Apple material.

A couple of years ago I would've said just use the text, especially if this is just some small project.....but with people giving out lawsuits over nothing I think you might wanna ping them and ask.